# How to tell scientist from pilot from engineer?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I know that when you pick kerbals for a mission it tells you what their role is, but I didn't even pay attention to who was placed on my ships when I launched, and now I have a space station with 5 kerbals with unknown roles!

Is there a way to tell what their roles are? I sent some of them to Minmus, and as soon as I completed my intercept burn I saw a message flash on the screen telling me I have no pilots aboard, so my SAS is disabled. I thought it wouldn't be a big problem, as this shuttle craft is easy to control, but EVERYTHING shut down! No SAS, no main engine, no RCS, nothing! They were on the way to deep space in a rock!

I loaded my quicksave and tried to find a pilot to go on this mission, but realized there is NO WAY to know who does what! This is unacceptable. To require roles (especially in sandbox mode) and not identify the kerbals' role is just ridiculous! I now have 5 useless kerbals in a space station orbiting the Mun, unless someone can tell me how to identify roles.

Squad, you need to have different uniforms for different roles, or at the very least, have the role show up when you right click!! This is asinine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go back to KSC and look in the Astronaut Complex. Kerbals on a mission are listed there, too.

Comment: Thank you Earl! I did check all of the kerbals who are in the space station today and Jeb was the only pilot among them. Strangely enough, he was in the shuttle on the way to Minmus when the game claimed that there was no pilot aboard! The flight went well today despite having exactly the same kerbals aboard.

Comment: @KSPJunkie You're welcome. I think you encountered a bug. Not having a pilot available should just deny you using SAS. Also, I would really appreciate, you accepting my answer (=

Comment: A command module without a Kerbal in it won't let you control the ship; you probably had all your kerbals in a crew (not command) area.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way while flying is to got to map view (<kbd>M</kbd>) then click this button:

[image: Crew button]

That will bring up a list of all the Kerbals on your vessel as well as all the info about them.